# Install4j based installer hangs and exits with last message in log file as 'creating jvm'

Tags: crash, jvm, install4j

While installing our product built on Install4j platform on one of the windows 10 machines, a customer got this error. The installer uses bundled JRE 8. The machine used Denmark-Danish as language. The problem is consistently reproducible on this machine.

I tried the following as part of my support diagnosis:

1. Started installer from command prompt as Administrator
2. Tried silent installer using response file
3. Tried 32 bit as well as 64 bit versions of installer

In all the cases, the end result was the same. I would appreciate any help to move forward.

-Djava.class.path=C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\i4jruntime.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\platform.zip;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\commons-validator-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\datasource-updater.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\guava-25.1-jre.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\httpclient-4.3.6.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\httpcore-4.3.3.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\install4j-itko-all-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\lisa-annotations-10.5.0.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\lisa-core-10.5.0.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\lisa-modules-10.5.0.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\lisa-util-10.5.0.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\w24910\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j3E19.tmp_dir1564126426\user\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;

**Creating JVM**

Comment: Have you tried a different JRE bundle or no JRE bundle?

Comment: No, I am an user of the installer and not the developer.

Comment: Do you have any of the following environment variables set: _JAVA_OPTIONS, JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS, JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS

Comment: I am not sure. This issue was reported by a customer. Sure, I will check for these and disable them. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who chipped in. Apparently the drive on which customer tried the installer didnt have enough space. This was a bit of surprise for the dev team as well as we have space checks in place and in spite of having adequate space, creating JVM has failed. Something for us to tinker with the installer code.